# Rails 3 Ajax link_to :method => :delete not working

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got Ajax working on a create action in my Rails 3 app, so I have the proper files and everything. I'm attempting to also destroy using Ajax, but I'm having trouble. My app deletes it but I have to refresh my view for the object to be removed - it remains until I refresh. Here's what I see in rails server:

```
Started DELETE "/awards/6" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Nov 28 15:12:45 -0500 2011
  Processing by AwardsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"6"}
  Award Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "awards".* FROM "awards" WHERE "awards"."id" = '6' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.5ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"awards"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum
  AREL (0.6ms)  DELETE FROM "awards" WHERE "awards"."id" = 6
  SQL (1.1ms)  COMMIT
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on? Here's my code:

`awards_controller.rb`:

```
def create
  @award = Award.new(params[:award])
  @award.save!
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to profile_path(@profile) }
    format.js { }
  end
end

def destroy
  @award = Award.find(params[:id])
  @award.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to profile_path(@profile) }
    format.js { render :nothing => true }
  end
end
```

The HTML in my view:

```
<div id="awardList">
  <ul id="awardInfo">
    <li>-&nbsp;Test<span class="delete"><a href="/awards/6" class="delete_award" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to remove this award?" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">x</a></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="newActivity">
  <form></div>
  ...
  </form>
</div>
</div><!-- end activitiesawards -->
```

`link_to :method => :delete`:

```
<%= link_to 'x', award_path(award), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to remove this award?", :class => "delete_award" %>
```

`awards/destroy.js.erb`:

```
$("ul#awardInfo<%= (@award) %>").remove();
```

My `Award.rb` model:

```
class Award < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

My `Profile.rb` model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :awards
end
```

Comment: I had this problem before and nothing i tried worked, but if you are in a hurry, try this pure javascript for now: <%= link_to("x", award_path(award), {:onclick => "return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this award?')", :method => :delete, :remote => true}, :class => "delete_award") %>

Comment: Thanks, but I'd really like the Rails UJS way on this. You had the same problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this chunk

```
"ul#awardInfo<%= (@award) %>"
```

should be

```
"ul#awardInfo_<%= @award.id %>"
```

and in view

```
"id="awardInfo"
```

id must be unique, so try

```
id="awardInfo_#{@award.id}"
```

in your view.

Comment: Lifesaver. I ended up changing my `destroy.js` to `"#awardInfo li.<%= (@award.id) %>"`, and in my view added `<li class="<%= award.id %>">`. You were right - the award needed a unique ID to target. You have no idea how much this helped.

Comment: I'm glad that my experience was helpful to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you are calling `render :nothing => true`with the js response, thus the js template is not being called.

Just left it blank (`{}`) so the default template is called and you should be ok.

Comment: I've tried that but for some reason it didn't change anything.